# JQuery not working at all in Opera

Tags: jquery, opera

I've encountered a puzzling problem: JQuery completely breaks in Opera. I have current versions of both (JQuery 1.3, Opera 9.27).

My website uses JQuery cycle, an animated slide show plug in, shown in this page:

http://www.donotbendinc.com/index.php/projects/detail/ultrinsic/

It also uses Opacity, which makes images dim on Rollover:

[same homepage]/index.php/projects/category/category/branding/

All these work perfectly in Safari and FF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is jQuery not working, or just the cycle plugin?  The way you phrase it sounds like jQuery, but then the example you give uses a plugin.  Do basic jQuery selections work for you? e.g. $('div');

Comment: Well, I'm assuming it's JQuery because neither Cycle or Opacify work. To tell the truth, I don't know how to find out if $('div') works...

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out--there is newer version of Opera for Mac, v 10. Weird how it completely breaks in 9.27.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with Opera 10 for Windows.  Perhaps you need to clear your cache to get the latest code.